# Generic method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a created a generic class in asp.net named `BasketController`, now `BasketController` handles 2 types of functionality `AnonymousBasket` and `UserBasket`, so i have created generic method to add product to basket, now based on `Type` specified by user, it will add products. Below is the class i have created:

```
public class BasketController<T>
    {
        public void AddProduct<T>(T obj)
        {
            if (obj is AnonymousBasket)
            {
                AnonymousBasket anon = obj as AnonymousBasket;
                SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Global.ConnectionString, "Basket_Add", new object[] { Enumerations.BasketType.Anonymous, anon.AnonymouseBasketID, anon.PackageID, anon.PurchasedUnits });
            }
            else
            {
                UserBasket anon = obj as UserBasket;
                SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Global.ConnectionString, "Basket_Add", new object[] { Enumerations.BasketType.User, anon.UserID, anon.PackageID, anon.PurchasedUnits });
            }

        }
    }
```

Now my problem is i have to specify SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery method twice as i cannot know the type of class until it's passed `if` conditions, is there anyway i can specify the SqlHelper outside `if` condition, so that i need to call SqlHelper only once.

Comment: Do you need a generic method? Why not add two methods, One for `AnonymousBasket` and another for `UserBasket`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface like below

```
interface IBasket
{
}
```

and inherit your classes from IBasket like below

```
AnonymousBasket: IBasket
{
}

UserBasket : IBasket
{
}
```

Now as IBasket is parent interface so you can use it's reference to add the data into database. 
Change your mthod as follows

```
public void AddProduct(IBasket basket)
{

}
```

Comment: *Now as IBasket is parent class* ? `IBasket` is implemented interface, not a class.

Comment: Whilst (potentially) correct, it doesn't explain how adding an interface would solve the OP's problem, they will still be stuck with the if statement and the problem they are trying to resolve

Comment: Hi @Șhȇkhaṝ, can you tell me how making an interface could solve my problem, because even with this i have to create 2 classes anonymous and user which i wanted to avoid and make single generic class, because both has same functionality the only difference is from anonymous basket i will get anonymousbasketid, and from userbasket i will get userid

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public class BasketController<T>
    {
        public void AddProduct<T>(T obj)
        {
            object[] _objects;
            if (obj is AnonymousBasket)
            {
                AnonymousBasket anon = obj as AnonymousBasket;
                _objects = new object[] { Enumerations.BasketType.Anonymous, anon.AnonymouseBasketID, anon.PackageID, anon.PurchasedUnits };
            }
            else
            {
                UserBasket anon = obj as UserBasket;
                _objects = new object[] { Enumerations.BasketType.User, anon.UserID, anon.PackageID, anon.PurchasedUnits };
            }
            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Global.ConnectionString, "Basket_Add", _objects);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (added as a separate answer, to let the voters decide which one is best) would be to just have a property (or method) on your basket types that gets the enum type for you. Say you define them on a common interface:

```
public interface IBasket
{
    Guid ID { get; set; }
    // other basket properties
    Enumerations.BasketType Type { get; }
}
```

and then you let each type provide their own implementation:

```
public class UserBasket : IBasket
{
    // Implementaiton of other basket properties
    Enumerations.BasketType Type { get { return Enumerations.BasketType.User; } }
}
```

Now, you don't even need a ternary statement - each basket knows its type. So now you could do

```
public void AddProduct(IBasket basket)
{
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("Add_Basket", new object[] {
        basket.Type,
        basket.ID,
        basket.PackageID,
        basket.PurchasedUnits
    });
}
```

Note that this is **future proof**: if you want to add a new basket type in the future, just add another type that implements `IBasket`, and that returns something relevant from the `Type` parameter. This method will just continue working without change.

Comment: Hi @Tomas Lycken thanks for the reply, let me tell you what i understood from above, i will have 2 classes (Anon and User (Basket)) and an Interface, interface will have a definition for BasketType property and will return the actual property with the specified class(Anonymous or User) and will have another class known as BasketController and that will be having AddProduct method right?

Comment: @Abbas: Right. The interface defines a property `Type` with a getter, so all types that implement it need to have this property. So for every basket type you want (currently `AnonymousBasket` and  `UserBasket` you create such a getter, on the basket type. The `AddProduct` method (on your controller) can then make use of the `Type` property to insert correct data into the SQL statement. (By the way, doing this effectively makes your basket types *data transfer objects*, or DTOs, since they now have a property for every piece of data that you want them to convey.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the only difference in the two versions is the enum type, right?

Use an interface, which defines the properties you need:

```
interface IBasket {
    Guid ID { get; set; } // use for AnonBasketID or UserID depending on implementation
    Guid PackageID { get; set; }
    int PurchasedUnits { get; set; }
}
```

Then, let your basket types implement this interface, and use a ternary statement to determine the enum type:

```
public void AddProduct(IBasket basket)
{
    var type = (basket is UserBasket) 
               ? Enumerations.BasketType.User 
               : Enumerations.BasketType.Anonymous;

    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("Basket_Add", new object[] { 
                                                            type, 
                                                            basket.ID, 
                                                            basket.PackageID,
                                                            basket.PurchasedUnits 
                                                          });
    // Yes, I do funky things with whitespace to avoid scrollbars on SO...
}
```